# Android Emulator: Audio Input Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Whenever I attempt to launch an emulator these errors appear in the console:

```
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
```

Everything else in the emulator still works besides the audio. Has anyone found a solution to this issue? Switching the Graphics option on the AVD to Software - GLES 2.0 did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Here how to fix this:

1. Go to Control Panel->Sound->Recording.
2. Make sure your default hardware, "Realtek Audio Default Device" (the one integrated in the motherboard) is enabled.

I disabled it by mistake trying to get my speakers to work and completely forgot...

Answer (score 2):

Phil's answer is correct but I can't comment on it directly:

This happens because ... There is in fact no available host audio input (nothing plugged to PC "audio in" or PC "audio in" already in use and cannot be shared)!

this was enough to get to complete the apk build and run on an AVD (API level 21 + android 5.0 / x86_64,      with  gpu graphics: Software GLES 1.1)

Under Windows start -> Control_panel-> Sound-> Recording -> microphone -> disable

-untested: 
-mic disabled + hardware graphics
- As Phil suggested, mic plugged in probably works around the bug

I'd guess a mic is a requirement for working with Pixel AVD's that has been accidental applied to older non-pixel avds.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug and probably simply happens because... There is in fact no available host audio input (nothing plugged to PC "audio in" or PC "audio in" already in use and cannot be shared)!

Under Windows, please check into Control_panel->Sound->Recording that something is available as input, and if so, close any application that may exclusively use it (skype?).

Answer (score 1):

For me it wasn't working because I was remotely logged in to PC with emulator. Had to allow record audio in Remote Desktop settings (Local Resources tab -> Remote audio -> Settings -> Allow remote audio recording)

Comment: This solution worked for me over Remote Desktop to my office PC where the Android emulator is running.  There were no Input devices (i.e. microphone) when I was originally connected via Remote Desktop.  After changing this setting then Windows 10 settings show "Input: [Remote Audio]" and it already showed "Output: [Remote Audio]"

Answer (score 0):

Plugin something in the microphone pin and voila.. the error goes away... for some reason, it needs the microphone .. AMD Ryzen 1600, the hypervisor is on, windows 10 pro 1903.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the bug was through the included headphones (with the microphone) by **USB**