# Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I run the emulator in android studio , the following error appears.

```
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
```

I could not find any solutions for this. Any solutions ?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234091/android-emulator-audio-input-failed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Emulator: Audio Input Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234091/android-emulator-audio-input-failed)